# Is it possible to calculate an average correlation of r from several correlations of r?

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, pearson-r

Any help would be appreciated. I have a table presenting multiple r correlations between various formats of the same test and the construct/dimensions it purports to measure. Is there an acceptable way in which to calculate an average correlation of all the constructs/dimensions related to one format of the test please?

Comment: Have you considered searching our site for ["average correlation"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=average+correlation)?